# Convert CLA to Double

Tags: java, double, command-line-arguments

I need to ask the user for 4 command-line arguments, then use those values for computation in my program. My question is, how do I convert the CLA's to type double? Also, if they don't enter the correct number of CLA's I need to print an error. When would I check for this (i.e. before my computation or after)?

Comment: I fixed my parse.Double part of the code. Now I'm not sure how to code the error statement? I have: 

if (args.length != 4) {
            System.out.println("ERROR - Command Line Arguments");
            }

But it prints out: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at QuadFormula.main(QuadFormula.java:13)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Double#parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble) method.
It returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the specified String and throws `NumberFormatException` if entered string is not a number.
for example

```
try{
    Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
}catch(NumberFormatException ne){
    System.out.println("Please enter a Double");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you get CLA you get a `String` so you can use

```
Double d = new Double(str);
```

you can parse it:

```
Double d = Double.parse(str);
```